# How to add 8 bit depth GIF images in wp7?

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, gif

I have some images of 8 bit depth and 24 bit depth GIF images.While its supporting 24 bit depth GIF images but 8 bit depth images are not shown at all.

I have changed the appmanifest BitsPerPixel=32 then to its not working.Anybody can tell how to get it fix.thanx

Comment: There doesn't exist any such thing as 24-bit GIF. GIFs are at max 8-bit or 256 colors (bitplane and palette based).

Comment: k anybody have any idea how to convert a GIF image to jpeg one.

Comment: or how to add GIf images to wp7 application using their url(on web).